# What are the traffic item ID's from HERE's traffic API?

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to understand the system of unique IDs that are returned by any traffic API request - in particular, I want to know what `ORIGINAL_TRAFFIC_ITEM_ID` and `TRAFFIC_ITEM_ID` refer to.

The full example of an API return is [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/dev_guide/topics/example-incidents-localization.html), but the relevant tags I'm looking at are below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<TRAFFICML_INCIDENTS TIMESTAMP="05/30/2018 14:35:34" VERSION="2.4" TIMESTAMP2="2018-05-30T14:34:35Z" EXTENDED_COUNTRY_CODE="E0">
  <TRAFFIC_ITEMS>
    <TRAFFIC_ITEM mid="16016752_original|1527204973573" PRODUCT="basic">
     <TRAFFIC_ITEM_ID>1144065005844396636</TRAFFIC_ITEM_ID>
     <ORIGINAL_TRAFFIC_ITEM_ID>1144065005844396636</ORIGINAL_TRAFFIC_ITEM_ID>
     .
     .
     .
    </TRAFFIC_ITEM>
  </TRAFFIC_ITEMS>
</TRAFFICML_INCIDENTS>
```

My working hypothesis is that `ORIGINAL_TRAFFIC_ITEM_ID` is persistent for that incident across time that this incident is observed (which is useful because the API returns real-time incident data), but then I'm not sure what `TRAFFIC_ITEM_ID` would be.

Is there documentation on this somewhere? I've been looking but haven't been able to find anything so far. Would appreciate any pointers in the right direction!

Comment: thanks for pointing out the missing details in the documentation, we have raised the JIRA to our developer, we will update you asap on the same.

Answer (score 0):

The description of the tags are as follows :

```
Each TRAFFIC_ITEM tag provides information on a traffic incident in its body. 

Each 'traffic item' is uniquely identified by TRAFFIC_ITEM_ID.

ORIGINAL_TRAFFIC_ITEM_ID uniquely identifies incident. It won't change when an Incident updates.
```